# Qt creator doesnt work correctly while reading from file

Tags: c++, qt-creator

```
     inputfile = fopen("input_file.txt", "r");
    outputfile = fopen("output_file.txt", "w");
    char a[30];
 // fgets (a , 100 , inputfile);
   fscanf(inputfile, "%s", a);
```

I am using QtCreator. In class constructor when i use that codes and run, i just see "Press RETURN to exit" in terminal. But when i compile my program with g++ and run, it works well.

Probably there is a problem with fscanf or fgets in QtCreator. Because if i dont include that functions my program works also.

Comment: Qt Creator is IDE, not compiler, so you are compiling with same *gcc* anyway. But, always check if file IO functions succeed by checking return values and error codes. In this case you may have different working directory than what you think.

Comment: The most likely problem is that you do not have a file called `input_file.txt` in the same directory as the directory that the binary is being run from. The binary directory is usually **not** the same as the source directory when running from an IDE.

Comment: An additional note: You should always limit the length of the string you want to read according to the size of the buffer you pass. If e.g. the string your read is larger then 29 chars then the behaviour of your app will be undefined.

Comment: It sounds like an `XY problem `, doesn't it? Unlikely QtCreator is the problem indeed.

Comment: thanks to kaylum i solved my problem. I realized that binary and source directory is different. But i cant mark our question [SOLVED].

Comment: @hyde you are right but he wrote his answer in comments section. Now i can see his "answer" and i can check as best answer but i didnt see his comment in "answer" section before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely problem is that you do not have a file called input_file.txt in the same directory as the directory that the binary is being run from. The binary directory is usually not the same as the source directory when running from an IDE.